# XEN Guest error cannot open display

Tags: virtualization, xen, guest

**[XEN - dom0]** Ubuntu 12.04.5 server x64bit , using it on *CLI Mode - no GUI installed*

**[domU - guest]** *HVM guest* created via configuration file, I Determine the started DomU port attached with :

*# xm list --long  | grep location*

but when i try to connect to guest with vinagre after exporting $DISPLAY to 127.0.0.1:5900 (since I am using Ubuntu ) I get the error-warning [**Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display**] :

```
:~$ sudo vinagre 127.0.0.1:5900
:~$ (vinagre:process_number) : Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display
```

If i type (found it on google):

```
:~$ sudo vinagre 127.0.0.1:5900 >/dev/null 2>&1 &1 
I get this >>> : [1]<process_number>
```

and then nothing happens..

If I try to connect to domU via console (*sudo xm console* ) System stucks and I can't type or do something just reset via desktop button

Please ask me if you need further information about the problem .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question provides the answer - "no GUI installed". If there's no GUI installed (no X libraries), then there's no display for graphical programs to connect to.

Comment: So how am I supposed to install the guest HVM operating system and connect to it ?.. since _xm console_ crashes ? I chose not to install GUI package on main server because Nvidia drivers(I use nouveau drivers instead) + XEN don't work well and system doesn't boot at all / freezes / gets blackscreens..

Comment: You need a graphical display somewhere. It doesn't have to be on your hypervisor - you can SSH in to your hypervisor from another machine that does have an X server installed and simply forward X (for Red Hat and Fedora type Linuxes, use `ssh -Y` to accomplish this).

Comment: I truly love you .... Sorry for the late answer :D I Managed after so long to connect to it .. but when I do i get this error : `** (vinagre:5619): WARNING **: Failed to initialize mDNS browser: Failed to create avahi client: Daemon not running` and after _installation_ the guest VM **asked me to reboot and it crashed** : / I can't do something now, everytime I am trying to connect to it the page is black and grey with cubes all over the place, with GUI not showing up on vinagre !

Comment: Ok fixed it , the problem was on the `.config file` of the domU VM i was trying to spawn. . . Thanks a ton again lad for helping me out with this ..! !